# Read text file on remote computer on different domain

Tags: vbscript, automation, windows-xp, wmi

My below code is to find a word in a text file in server (`\\10.0.1.22\C$\Logs\text.txt`)

For User: `SBICAD\user` its working fine. (SBICAD is domain in server)

For User: `ThisComputer\user` it fails ("Logon failure: unknown username or bad password")

[image: Error message: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password]

Note: Im running the script on local machine XP. Server 2003 and Local Machine XP are in the same network.

```
dim objService 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputer = "10.0.1.22" 
strDomain = "SBICAD"
Const WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy = 6

Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _
  "root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk='c:'", _
  "administrator", _
  "jan@2014", _
  "MS_409", _
  "ntlmdomain:" + strDomain)

objSWbemServices.Security_.authenticationLevel = WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\C$\Logs\text.txt"
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath , ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  CurrentLine= objTextFile.ReadLine
  if ((InStr(1, CurrentLine, "James", 1) > 0) And (InStr(1, CurrentLine, "John", 1) > 0) )Then 
    Wscript.Echo "James and John Found"
  end if
Loop

objTextFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, because line 26 of the code you posted couldn't raise the error you described.

However, assuming I understand your question correctly the problem is that `ConnectServer` is raising the error when you try to authenticate with a local user from your local machine against a remote server. This doesn't work, because a local user on host A is unknown on the remote host B and thus cannot authenticate there:

[image: Authentication with local user on source host fails.]

You need either a user that is known on both hosts (which is what a domain provides):

[image: Authentication with domain user works.]

or a local user on the remote host B:

[image: Authentication with local user on destination host works.]

---

With that said, why are you trying to establish a WMI connection in the first place? You never use it anywhere in your code, and it won't authenticate the SMB connection you're actually trying to use. SMB connections (access to file shares) must be authenticated [in a different way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

username   = "user"  'domain user or user on the remote host!
password   = "pass"
drive      = "S:"
remotePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\C$\Logs"

net.MapNetworkDrive drive, remotePath, False, username, password
```

Then you can work read files on the remote location like this:

```
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("S:\text.txt")

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  ...
Loop

objTextFile.Close
```

After you're finished you can remove the network drive like this:

```
net.RemoveNetworkDrive drive, True
```

Note that the user account must have administrative privileges on the remote host to be able to access the administrative share `C$`. It might be a good idea to create a dedicated share that allows non-admin access to the log directory.